# Make a shape go in an angular direction

Tags: java, processing, angle, direction

I'm making Asteroids and I was trying to make the bullet mechanic. The bullet should go in the ship facing direction (an angle), but I don't know how to make the bullet go into that angular direction. Instead it goes up, down or right/left.
The code I tried and does not work:

```java
class Bullet
{
    float x,y,vx,vy;
    Bullet()
    {
        rectMode(CENTER);
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        vx = 100 * cos(ang);
        vy = 100 * sin(ang);
    }

    void draw2()
    {
        vx = 100 * cos(ang);
        vy = 100 * sin(ang);
        x += vx;
        y += vy;
        pushMatrix();
        translate(width/2,height/2);
        translate(5,0);
        rotate(ang);
        rect(x,y,10,10);
        popMatrix();
    }
}
```

The rest of the code:

```java
float ang = 0;
boolean spara = false;
Bullet b;

void setup()
{
    size(800,600);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    frameRate(60);
    asteroidi = new Asteroide[10];
    b = new Bullet();
}

void update()
{

}

void draw()
{
    update();
    background(200,200,200);
    fill(255);
    pushMatrix();
    translate(width/2,height/2);
    translate(25,0);
    rotate(ang);
    rect(0,0,50,50);
    popMatrix();
    if(spara)
        b.draw2();
}

void keyPressed()
{
    switch (keyCode)
    {
      case RIGHT:
          ang += 0.1;
          break;
      case LEFT:
          ang -= 0.1;
          break;
      case 32:
          if (spara) spara = false;
          if (!spara); spara = true;

          break;
    }
}
```

I call the `draw2()` function, when the `boolean spara` is `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to do the following:

- draw the bullet rectangle in that way, that it's center is at (0, 0):
  `rect(0, 0, 10, 10);`
- rotate rectangle in direction of move:
  `rotate(ang);`
- translate rectangle to new position:
  `translate(x, y);`

Since the operations like [`translate`](https://processing.org/reference/translate_.html) and [`rotate`](https://processing.org/reference/rotate_.html) define a new matrix and multiply the current matrix by the new matrix, the matrix operations have to be done in reverse order.

Note that the angle to [`sin()`](https://processing.org/reference/sin_.html) and [`cos()`](https://processing.org/reference/cos_.html) has to be set in radians ratherr than degrees.
By the way, are you sure that a velocity of 100 is not far to much?

```java
class Bullet
{
    float x, y, v, ang;
    Bullet(float x, float y, float v, float ang)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.v = v;
        this.ang = ang;
    }

    void update() {
        x += v * cos(ang);
        y += v * sin(ang);
    }

    void draw()
    {
        pushMatrix();

        // transalte rectangle to new position
        translate(x, y);

        // rotate rectangle in direction of move
        rotate(ang);

        // draw rectangle around center
        rect(0, 0, 10, 10);

        popMatrix();
    }
}
```

Manage the bullets in an [`ArrayList`](https://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html) and spawn (add) a new bullet when <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is pressed:

```java
ArrayList<Bullet> bullets = new ArrayList<Bullet>();

float ang = 0.7;
void keyPressed()
{
    switch (keyCode)
    {
        case RIGHT:
            ang += 0.1;
            break;
        case LEFT:
            ang -= 0.1;
            break;
        case 32:
            bullets.add(new Bullet(width/2, height/2, 2, ang));
            break;
    }
}
```

Update (move) all the bullets in the array in update. Keep just the bullets which are still in the window. Store the bullets which are in the window to a new array and replace the array of bullets by the new array:

```java
void update()
{
    // array for bullets which ar still in window
    ArrayList<Bullet> bulletsInWindow = new ArrayList<Bullet>();

    for( int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); ++i ) {
        Bullet b = bullets.get(i);

        // move bullet
        b.update();

        // evaluate eif bullet is still in window
        if ( b.x >= 0 && b.y >= 0 && b.x <= width && b.y <= height ) {
            bulletsInWindow.add(b);
        }
    }

    // keep the bullets which are still in the window
    bullets = bulletsInWindow;
}
```

Draw the bullets in a loop in `draw()`:

```java
void draw() 
{
    update();

    background(200,200,200);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    fill(255);

    for( int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); ++i ) {
        Bullet b = bullets.get(i);
        b.draw();
    }

    pushMatrix();
    translate(width/2,height/2);
    rotate(ang);
    rect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    popMatrix();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works. But it stands still, how do I make it move?

Comment: @GianMarcoCialdi What dos it mean "it stands still"? Every time when `draw2` is called, then `x` and `y` changes (rapidly because of `v=100`). Please respect that I can't see your code, I can just see the class `Bullet`. It is impossible for me to tell you what is wrong in the part of the code which I can't see.

Comment: Thanks! Since I won't do it with rectangles, what about with images?

Comment: @GianMarcoCialdi thank You. You're welcome. - *"what about with images?"* See [`image()`](https://processing.org/reference/image_.html). Create a [`PImage`](https://processing.org/reference/PImage.html) by [`loadImage()`](https://processing.org/reference/loadImage_.html) and draw it by `image()`.